# Angular JS - Decorate a service with the controller name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am unclear of exactly how `decorator` works in conjunction with the angular `$injector`, so any explanation is helpful.

Considering my `myTempService`:

```
$provide.decorator('myTempService', function($delegate) {
  $delegate.controller = // some service to get the current controller
  return $delegate;
});
```

When `myTempService` is injected into my controller, I need `myTempService.controller` to be the controller's name:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function (myTempService) {
   console.log(myTempService.controller); // MainCtrl
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `.value()`, `.service()`, `.factory()` and `.provider()` to register a service, what you pass in as the second parameter will actually be ended up as a part of a **Service Provider Constructor**.

When an angular's bootstrap process begin, each of those registered service provider constructors will be used to create a **Service Provider Instance**.

During a Configuration Phase, the service provider instances are available to be injected, and you can use them to change default configuration of to be created service instances.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {
  // $httpProvider is a provider instance of the $http service
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {});
});
```

Before entering a Run Phase, each of service provider instance will be used to create a **Service Instance**.

Then the **Decorators** will come into play at this point. Before those service instances will be used for injecting to various places, each service instance will be passed into its registered decorators as `$delegate` parameter if any. **The result of the decorator function will be used instead of the 
original service instance**.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$http', function ($delegate) {
    // monkey patching
    var originalGet = $delegate.get;
    $delegate.get = function () {
      console.log('$http.get is called');
      return originalGet.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Therefore, in a decorator function, you have choices to:

- Just do something and return the original service instance e.g. print out something for debugging purpose.
- Set initial values of the service, that for some reasons cannot be done in a config phase.
- Monkey patch the original service instance and return it.
- Create and return a wrapper/proxy service over the original service instance.
- In unit testing, you could return a mock/spy object instead.

Finally, the service instances will be available for injecting into all of the places e.g. run blocks, controllers, directives, filters etc. for the entire life of the application.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clearing some of that up. Perhaps I should be asking, how do I intercept the instance that the $injector puts in my controller, so that I am augment this instance with some value that can be used to associate it with the controller.

Comment: Not sure I'm understand your question correctly. For each service, the service instance will be created only once, and this only same instance will be injected into anything that request it. So it's not possible to know which controller is requesting the service in the decorator function.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. Thank you for clearing that up - it's impossible, so there doesn't seem to be any good answer to this using $decorator. Thank you